# Open a Pop Up from bottom when tab bar item is clicked in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, popup, uitabbaritem

How to show `Bottom PopUp` when `TabBar` index 2 is clicked and hide when "`close`" button inside `PopUp` is clicked and also when popup shows tab bar will be hidden.Could someone help me i am new to iOS development.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to design a UIView on HomeTabBarViewController Like this

For Example:-

[image]

And drag and drop IBOutlet for that UIView

```
@IBOutlet weak var demoView: UIView!
```

And set isHidden property as false in viewDidLoad Method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    demoView.isHidden = false
}
```

Now on cross button set isHidden property as true

```
@IBAction func crossBtnPrsd(_ sender: Any) {
    demoView.isHidden = true
}
```

[image]

Comment: i have to show that pop up when index of third tab bar is clicked and close when click on close button of that view

Comment: you have to design UIView On transactionViewController

Comment: means i have a tab bar controller and also a ViewController for each index but third index i have no viewcontroller i want to show pop up and suppose if index 0 ViewController is opened and suddendly i clicked on 3rd index then pop will show and in background index 0 ViewController will also shown

Comment: you have 3 viewController right news ,home and Popular in storyboard ?so u have to add UIView on third tabbarviewcontoller

Comment: pls read my above comment i have 5 viewcontrollers embedded in tab bar controller

Comment: but you have to add view controller for 3 index also because you have to design UIview for popup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180917/discussion-between-ashwani5389-and-tabassum).